# How to trigger the animation time in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

For now my code is has an eventListener for video files. So soon as the video is finished the function starts. But instead to have a video file I want to create an animation. And soon as that animation is ended I want the function to start.

```
<div id="intro" class="exitBtnCol">
    <video id="intro_text" width="728" height="90" autoplay>
        <source src="intro_text_video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="intro_text_video.webM" type="video/webM">
    </video>
</div>
```

```js
openerVid.addEventListener( 'ended', startResolve, false);
```

this is what I have now.

Comment: Videos and animations are like apples and oranges...

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I read it that the OP wants to start an animation when the video ends and then call his function - but you could be right.

Comment: so whats the point? if the taste is different both are comestible

Comment: No, what I want is to remove the video and instead that to have an animation. And soon as the animation is ended the function startResolve to be called

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `animate()` method to perform an animation on an element. This method also takes a callback function as a parameter when you can call `startResolve()` from when the animation ends. Try this:

```
$(openerVid).on('ended', function() {
    $('#foo').animate({
        opacity: 1 // change as required
    }, 500, startResolve);
});
```